# Android RoomDatabase - Could not resolve android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0

Tags: android, gradle

```
Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.

Could not resolve android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0. Required by: project :app

No cached version of android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0 available for offline mode.
No cached version of android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0 available for offline mode.
No cached version of android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0 available for offline mode.
No cached version of android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0 available for offline mode.
No cached version of android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0 available for offline mode.
No cached version of android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0 available for offline mode.
No cached version of android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0 available for offline mode.
No cached version of android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0 available for offline mode.
```

Room gradle dependecies

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

Offline mode and build cache are disabled. Gradle version 4.1
Gradle project file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add `google()` as maven dependency to your project?

Comment: @Christopher yes

Comment: Did u tried Invalidate cache and restart. Invalidate Cache by tapping File-> option in android studio

Comment: @lib4 cache invalidating not helps. Strange, gradle sync successful, but when I trying to Make Project this error occurs

Comment: please add `google()` also in the project-repository section, not only in the `buildscript` section.

Comment: you should add this project level section instead of Module section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could not resolve android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0

To add it to your project, open the **`build.gradle`** file for your project **`(Project Level)`** and add the highlighted line as shown below:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

**DEMO**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Kindly read [**`Adding Components to your Project`**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html)

Comment: + File -> Settings -> Build, Execution... -> Compiler -> add command --refresh-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you might be using **Offline mode** in your Android Studio. To disable **Offline mode**:

1. Make sure your machine is connected to the internet.
2. Go to **File** -> **Settings** & expand **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Gradle** -> **UNCHECK Offline work** -> **OK**
3. Go to **File** -> click on **Invalidate Caches / Restart** -> **Invalidate & Restart**
4. Done

Comment: Invalidating the cache and restarting was enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `google()` maven repo to your project (two occurences):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    // Your other Maven Repos
  }
}
```